# Active Admin - dropdown for row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu, activeadmin

I am building a show page for a BcUser model, and I would like to include a row that enables the admin to choose a law firm for the user from a drop-down. Right now I have the following:

```
show :title => :first_name do |bc_user|
  attributes_table do
    row :id
    row('First Name', :sortable => :first_name) {|bc_user|bc_user.first_name }
    row('Last Name', :sortable => :last_name) {|bc_user| bc_user.last_name }
    row 'Law Firm' do
      select :law_firm, options_for_select(LawFirm.all.collect{|l| [l.name, l.token]})
    end
  end
end
```

which returns:

```
<tr class="row row-law_firm">
  <th>Law Firm</th>
  <td>
    <select>law_firm</select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

There are two law firms in the system and I would like to know why I am returning no options for select?

**EDIT #1**
After playing around, I was able to produce something close to what I want, but it omits the first option:

```
show :title => :first_name do |bc_user|
  attributes_table do
    row :id
    row('First Name', :sortable => :first_name) {|bc_user|bc_user.first_name }
    row('Last Name', :sortable => :last_name) {|bc_user| bc_user.last_name }
  end
  panel 'Law Firm'do
    table_for(bc_user) do
      column 'Law Firm' do
        select :law_firm_id, collection: options_for_select(LawFirm.all.collect{|l| ["#{l.name}, #{l.token}", l.token]})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Returns:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd" id="bc_user_2">
    <td class="col col-law_firm">
      <select collection="<option value=" 0331b8b0da9c"="">Daniel INC, 0331b8b0da9c <option value="66a8ff8ba7c1">Jason Inc, 66a8ff8ba7c1</option>"&gt;law_firm_id</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The first option, Daniel INC... isnt being shown in the menu.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @User089247 - I should have clarified that, just edited.

Comment: Seems like you want to show a select box without a form, any good reason for doing that?

Comment: Yea, the Senior Developer who gave me this assignment instructed me to create a dropdown menu for selecting which law firm a BcUser belongs to on the BcUser show page within Active Admin, which will trigger ajax to perform the action. I know it is clunky but he doesnt want this on a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work, and I still have no clue as to why I needed to insert a blank string at the beginning of the collection array. Perhaps this has to do with active admin changing the formatting around. This is what I came up with for anyone who runs into this problem:

```
panel 'Law Firm'do
  table_for(bc_user) do
    column 'Law Firm' do
      select :law_firm_id, collection: options_for_select(LawFirm.all.collect{|l| ["#{l.name}, #{l.token}", l.token]}.unshift(''))
    end
  end
end
```